# In powershell show do I set an environment variable thats a variable itself?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I would like to do this:

```
$jobName = ((get-item (get-location)).parent.name).ToUpper()
cd module\build
$current = pwd
$env:APP_HOME_$jobName = $current
```

but I get:

```
Unexpected token 'jobName' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:23
+ $env:APP_HOME_$jobName <<<<  = $current
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (jobName:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

How do I set an environment variable that is based on another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new-item` let's you pass a string to create your environment variable with the embedded variable. Like this:

```
new-item -Path "env:APP_HOME_$jobName" -Value $current
```

Note, if you need to update it after it already exists, just use `set-item` in the same way:

```
set-item -Path "env:APP_HOME_$jobName" -Value $current
```